# cURL - can't get POST response

Tags: php, forms, post, curl

I'm trying a basic thing. I have two files:
curl.php and
form.php

**curl.php**

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/test/test34_curl_post/form.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'nabc' => 'fafafa'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

**form.php**

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="nabc" value="abc" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />

</form>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 echo '<br />Form sent!'.$_POST['nabc'];
}
?>
```

what I'm hoping to get is as the result of running curl.php, to see "Form sent!". It seems as if it wasn't sent as POST. In firebug (network) there is only one GET request and what I get is the form, nothing sent. Anyone, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending `'submit'` in your POST data so `isset($_POST['submit'])` will be false. You need to do the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'nabc' => 'fafafa',
    'submit' => 'Send' // if you want 'submit' in $_POST you need this
));
```

Comment: Btw: maybe you know how to do that when there is:<form onsubmit="document.form1.submit();" name="form1" method="post" action="process.php">

Comment: `onsubmit="document.form1.submit()"` is pointless because the only way it could be triggered is by submitting `form1`. I think it's best if you submit another question with the details.

Comment: just to give you the idea, i don't know if it's enough for another question:http://web.copart.com/cgi-bin/counter/login.dtw/disp

Comment: Just add `<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Send"/>` to the form - get rid of `onsubmit="...`

Comment: I only provide the form with data. I'm trying to log in and get a cookie.